# send payara logs to graylog via syslog and set correct source

Tags: rsyslog, payara, graylog

I have a graylog instance that's running a UDP-Syslog-Input on Port 1514.
It's working wonderfully well for all the system logs of the linux servers.

When I try to ingest payara logs though [1], the "source" of the message is set to "localhost" in graylog, while it's normally the hostname of the sending server.

This is suboptimal, because in the best case I want the application logs with correct source in graylog also.

I googled around and found:

https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/payara-server-5.2021.5/nucleus/core/logging/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/server/logging/SyslogHandler.java#L122

It seems like the syslog "source" is hard-coded into payara (localhost).
Is there a way to accomplish sending payara-logs with the correct "source" set?

I have nothing to do with the application server itself, I just want to receive the logs with the correct source (the hostname of the sending server).

**example log entry in /var/log/syslog for payara**

```
Mar 10 10:00:20 localhost [ INFO glassfish ] Bootstrapping Monitoring Console Runtime
```

I suspect I want the "localhost" in above example set to *fqdn* of the host.

Any ideas?

Best regards

[1]
logging.properties:com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging=true

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling "store full message" in the syslog input settings.

That will add the full_message field to your log messages and will contain the header, in addition to what you see in the message field. Then you can see if the source IP is in the UDP packet. If so, collect those messages via a raw/plaintext UDP input and the source should show correctly.

You may have to parse the rest of the message via an extractor or pipeline rule, but at least you'll have the source....

Comment: Hi, @Blackbox thanks for pointing that out. I tried it with the full_message, but unfortunately it's not including the IP address or anything useful. 

The source field is also still set to "localhost". 

`full_message
<30>1 2021-08-01T01:00:00+02:00 localhost  - - -  INFO glassfish ] 01:00:00.224 [__ejb-thread-pool11] WARN  de.project.ejb.mlc.beans.MLCServiceBean - Could not do what I was told to do.`
I still have no idea how to get this working...

Answer (score 0):

Well,

this might not exactly be a good solution but I tweaked the rsyslog template for graylog.

I deploy the rsyslog-config via Puppet, so I can generate "$YOURHOSTNAME-PAYARA" dynamically using the facts.

This way, I at least have the correct source set.

```
$template GRAYLOGRFC5424,"<%PRI%>%PROTOCOL-VERSION% %TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% YOURHOSTNAME-PAYARA %APP-NAME% %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %msg%\n"

if $msg contains 'glassfish' then {
*.* @loghost.domain:1514;GRAYLOGRFC5424
& ~
} else {
*.* @loghost.domain:1514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
}
```

The other thing we did is actually activating application logging through log4j and it's syslog appender:

```
<Syslog name="syslog_app" appName="DEMO" host="loghost" port="1514" protocol="UDP" format="RFC5424" facility="LOCAL0" enterpriseId="">
                        <LoggerFields>
                                <KeyValuePair key="thread" value="%t"/>
                                <KeyValuePair key="priority" value="%p"/>
                                <KeyValuePair key="category" value="%c"/>
                                <KeyValuePair key="exception" value="%ex"/>
                        </LoggerFields>
                </Syslog>
```

This way, we can ingest the glassfish server logs and the independent application logs into graylog.

The "LoggerFields" in log4j.xml appear to be key-value pairs for the "StructuredDataElements" according to RFC5424.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with UDP Syslog. The sender gets to set the source in the header. There is no "best answer" to this question. When the information isn't present, it's hard for Graylog to pass it along.

It sounds like you may have found an answer that works for you. Go with it. Using log4j solves two problems and lets you define the source yourself.

For those who face a similar issue, a simpler way to solve the source problem might be to use a static field. If you send the payara syslog messages to their own input, you can create a static field that could substitute for the source to identify traffic from that source. Call it "app_name" or "app_source" or something and use that field for whatever sorting you need to do.

Alternatively, if you have just one source for application messages, you could use a pipeline to set the value of the source field to the IP or FQDN of the payara server. Then it displays like all the rest.